# Seed Fixed TensorFlow code with activation function not reproducible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, random-seed

I'm a complete beginner in deep learning who started studying DL a month ago. While studying the LSTM model, I am trying to improve model performances after fixing random seeds. However, I realized that even though I fixed the random seed (I've tried a lot of methods on the Internet and stackoverflow myself), when I restarted the runtime, I couldn't reproduce the same result. I am using Google Colab CPU and Tensorflow version 2.13.0. Then I realized that the result was not reproduced only when the activation function was added to the LSTM model.

I made this code to fix random seeds and used it for my LSTM model. (I've tried various things to fix random seeds, sorry in advance if there's a weird mix of codes) This code doesn't reproduce the same result when I restart Runtime on Google Colab.

```
import os
os.environ["PYTHONHASHSEED"] = '0'
os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'
os.environ['TF_CUDNN_DETERMINISTIC'] = '1'
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""

import numpy as np
import random as rn
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam


def seed_everything(seed=42):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    tf.random.set_seed(seed)
    rn.seed(seed)
    tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(seed)

    tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()
    config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(
        intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
        inter_op_parallelism_threads=1
    )
    session = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
    tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(session)


def create_lstm_model():
    seed_everything()

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(63, input_shape=(3, 1),
                            kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                             dropout=0.11, activation='relu', return_sequences=True),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(63, input_shape=(3, 1), kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                             dropout=0.11,  activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')
    ])

    return model


seed_everything()

input_data = np.random.rand(100, 3, 1)
target_data = np.random.rand(100, 1)

for i in range(4):
    print(f"Case {i + 1}:")

    model = create_lstm_model()

    indices = np.arange(len(input_data))
    np.random.shuffle(indices)
    input_data_shuffled = input_data[indices]
    target_data_shuffled = target_data[indices]

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.002)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse')

    early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)

    model.fit(input_data_shuffled, target_data_shuffled, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=0, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stopping])

    loss = model.evaluate(input_data, target_data, verbose=0)
    print(f"Loss: {loss}")
```

On the other hand, if the activation function is removed from the model as shown below, the same result is reproduced each runtime is restarted. It doesn't seem reasonable to not use the activation function to create a reproducible LSTM model. Is there a way to reproduce the results using my model? Thank you.

```
def create_lstm_model():
    seed_everything()

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(63, input_shape=(3, 1),
                            kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                             dropout=0.11, return_sequences=True),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(63, input_shape=(3, 1), kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                             dropout=0.11),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')
    ])

    return model
```

**(+)** I tried this method from @Nicolas' comment and it reproduces the result well, but the prediction performance of the model has changed significantly, so I wonder if the code I wrote is correct.

```
seed_everything()

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(63, input_shape=(3, 1),
                        kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                         dropout=0.11, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(63, input_shape=(3, 1), kernel_initializer=GlorotUniform(seed=42), recurrent_initializer=GlorotUniform(seed=42),
                         dropout=0.11),
    tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer=GlorotUniform(seed=42))
])

return model
```

Comment: If this is true, it seems like a bug you should report to Tensorflow. Does it work if instead of using the activation function in the LSTM layer, you add it like this between LSTM layers? `tf.keras.layers.ReLU()` ?

Comment: Hello @Nicolas, thank you for your kind comment. When activation functions are added between LSTM layers, the results seem to be reproduced. But the prediction performance has changed significantly, so I wonder if the code I wrote is correct. I have modified the text.